# Install two versions of an apk (with different applicationIds)

Tags: android, apk

How much do I have to change in an android project for it to be installed as a new app?

I thought that it would be enough to change the `applicationId` in the `build.gradle` file, but I am not able to install the second version of the app without uninstalling the first version. In the play store I get `error 910` or `error -505` and when installing it manually I get:

`Installation failed with message Failed to finalize session : INSTALL_FAILED_CONFLICTING_PROVIDER: Package couldn't be installed in /data/app/net.mindlevel-1: Can't install because provider name net.mindlevel (in package net.mindlevel) is already used by net.veglevel.
It is possible that this issue is resolved by uninstalling an existing version of the apk if it is present, and then re-installing.`

Do I have to change the package name in `AndroidManifest.xml` too?

`<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="net.mindlevel">`

And if I have change that, I have to change every single source file to use that package right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your manifest, there is a `<provider>` element with a hardcoded `android:authorities` attribute. That needs to be changed as well as your `applicationId`, as there can only be one provider installed for each unique authority.

Comment: That's it, that worked! Great that the solution was so simple.

Comment: @spydon: If this is your own app, consider changing your `android:authorities` value to use a manifest placeholder for the application ID (e.g., `android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"`). That way, the authority value automatically changes based on the `applicationId` value.

Comment: Even better! That was what I was looking for as a next step. Thanks for the help!